# How do I let baloo index files names and content but only in specific directories

Tags: kde, baloo

I have the problem of baloo being far too haevy on my I/O, and preventing me to work...

What I would like is to let ballo index file names only everywhere in my home, but also index contents in Documents only.

Is this possible ?